# Gremlin return one out vertex of current traversal

Tags: gremlin

If currently traversal includes [v1, v2, v3],
v1, v2, v3 all have multiple out vertices,
is it possible to use gremlin to return one out vertex for v1, v2, v3?

E.g.,

```
v1 out: [v4, v5]  
v2 out: [v6, v7]  
v3 out: [v8, v9]
```

Hope result can be sth like: [v4, v6, v8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to choose one of them in an arbitrary way you can use `local` and `limit`:

```
g.V().hasLabel('v1', 'v2', 'v3').local(out().limit(1))
```

if you have some logic to the filter you can do something like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('v1', 'v2', 'v3').local(out().order().by('value').limit(1))
```

example: https://gremlify.com/6r

Comment: good answer - I'd include that if you only care about the first item no mater what it is, you could replace `local()` with this `map(out())`